# bottle fraemwork. The counter does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does not it make me feel bad about the +1 flag? I can not understand.

Example of a json file:

```
{
How many will be 2 + 3?": [
        "+5",
        "-6",
        "-4",
        "-3"
    ]
}
```

My code:

```
  ul>
        <li>

            <div id="answers">
            %import json
            %import os

            %path2 = "/home/dark/fraemwork_bottle/bottle/static/templete/"
            %with open(os.path.join(path2, "test.json"), encoding="utf-8") as data_file:
                %data = json.load(data_file)
                %count = 1 #flag
                %for k, v in data.items():
                    <p>{{k}}</p>#qwestion
                    %for i in v:#Enumeration of values
                        %tru_line = "+"
                        %false_line = "-"
                        %if i[0] in tru_line:
                            <input type="radio" name="{{count}}" value="0">{{i[1:]}}<br>
                            %continue
                        %elif i[0]== false_line:
                            <input type="radio" name="{{count}}" value="1">{{i[1:]}}<br>
                            %continue
                    %count += 1#The flag does not work
            %end
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

name="{{count}}" 
All values ​​will always be 1. And I have 30 questions in the file, I can not correctly process the form.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have all of your files to work with I created this small template.

```
%count = 1
%for k, v in [(1,2), (3,4)]:
    <span>k: {{k}}</span><br>
    %for i in range(v):
        <span>i: {{i}}</span><br>

    %count += 1
    <span>count: {{count}}</span><br>
```

It seems to produce the expected results.

```
k: 1
i: 0
count: 2
i: 1
count: 3
k: 3
i: 0
count: 4
i: 1
count: 5
i: 2
count: 6
i: 3
count: 7
```

However, I notice that the `name` attributes in your `input` elements also have the value `count`. Is it possible that this is intering with your template code>